# SKScene deallocating during transition

Tags: memory-management, sprite-kit

I have few SKScenes with transitions between them. After transitions, the dealloc() is called (I checked it with NSLog). But my memory is still not going down. When dealloc() is called (automatically), does it mean, that all old SKScene is discarded (with all inside it), or do I have to care about some remaining stuff?
Thank you.

Comment: That highly depends on where you keep your allocated objects

Comment: Remove all strong references in your SKScenes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealloc of a class runs, it means that particular instance of the class has been released from memory.

However this does not tell you about any connected objects. For instance the biggest memory usage in Sprite Kit is typically the textures, and those are cached internally. A scene deallocating typically will see only a minimal decrease in memory as the textures remain in memory (for the time being or if they are in use by the new scene).